# How do I fix this 'transmission-daemon: command not found' error?

Tags: raspbmc, linux, apt

I set up a brand new Raspbmc and installed transmission-daemon on it. I was able to stop it by issuing a

`sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop`,

after which I proceed to make some changes to the **settings.json**, mainly to the download paths. My target folder was my NAS SMB share. I restarted the daemon and it was working. I was able to access it using the web UI and add a torrent to it and it even started downloading, but it failed due to a permissions problem.

Then I proceeded to add the user **pi** to **debian-transmission** as per some solutions and modified the **/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon script** to reflect the new username. After this, the daemon wouldn't start due to some error. I decided to start over - remove transmission and install it again - but after this, the daemon can no longer be started or stopped using the same command mentioned above. It keeps saying **sudo: /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon: command not found**.

How can I completely remove all traces of **transmission-daemon** including all config files and start afresh? My only hope at this point seems to be to wipe the card and redo Raspbmc and everything all over again...

Comment: give this a try assuming you installed using apt-get. sudo apt-get purge <package-name> replace <package-name> with your package's name.

Comment: @SteveRobillard that worked! Purging cleaned everything up, so I was able to reinstall and get it sorted. You should post this as an answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely remove a program and its configuration files use this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
```

replace  with your package's name, so in this case you would type:

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission-daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your installation of transmission-daemon

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission-daemon
```

Make sure the configuration files are removed

```
rm /etc/transmission-daemon/
```

Then follow [this tutorial](http://www.robertsetiadi.net/installing-transmission-in-raspberry-pi/) to reinstall transmission-daemon.

Also, make sure you use

```
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

to start the service, instead of `sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop`.